How to unify ergodic transformation and ergodic random process?
How to unify the concept of "ergodicity" (in particular, mean-ergodicity) in stochastic process and ergodic theory?
In stochastic process, Wiki says that a process $X(t)$ is said to be mean-ergodic if the time average estimate
\begin{equation}
    \hat{\mu_X} = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T X(t) dt
\end{equation}
converges to the ensemble average $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]$ in $\mathcal{L}^2$ sense.
In ergodic theory, Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem says that if a transformation $T$ is ergodic on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ (which means that $T$ is $\mathbb{P}$-preserving and $T$-invariant measurable sets are of measure 0 or 1), then for $\forall f \in \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{P}}^1$, the sequence of "time average" converges almost everywhere to a constant function $\mathbb{E}[f]$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
    \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f \circ T^i \right) \to  \mathbb{E}[f] = \int_{\Omega} f \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}, \quad \mathbb{P}-a.e.
\end{equation}
My questions:

I've seen different versions of the types of convergence, is it convergence almost everywhere, in $\mathcal{L}^2$ sense, in probability, or it depends on the space where $f$ lives?

I don't see any transformations in the definition of "mean-ergodicity" in stochastic process. How can I construct such transformation $T$ on what space in the first definition? Here is my mental picture for the two definitions, for the left one, just a single point $\omega \in \Omega$ determines a sample path, seems that no need for transformations on $\Omega$.



Maybe the following paragraph in Bremaud's Probability Theory and Stochastic Processes (P626) answers the second question, but how to understand it?


I've published in both areas and given talks on the connection.  To this day, I agree with you and have a similar discomfort with bridging these two areas.  Let me start by saying there are some textbooks and resources that help to better understand the connections.  For a classical understanding of the theory, I highly recommend Paul Shields' The Ergodic Theory of Discrete Sample Paths.  It is geared toward the questions that you are raising by showing how ergodic theory of measure preserving transformations applies in the context of statistics and probability.  Another resource that describes the various convergence properties (in distribution, in probability, in mean and almost everywhere) is here: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_4_convergence_in_distribution.php.  The field of ergodic theory tends to attract pure mathematicians and was born out of the results of Von Neumann, Birkhoff, Kolmogorov, Rokhlin, Halmos, Ornstein, Weiss, Furstenburg, Kakutani and many others (including Boltzmann who coined the term).  It is now a branch of dynamical systems (measurable dynamics) and concerns mostly the study of measure preserving transformations and flows on Lebesgue spaces.  The theoretical connection between this field and the study of stochastic processes is exactly what you said.  A stochastic process: $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ can be turned into a transformation and iterated by applying the shift map to the space of infinite or bi-infinite sequences obtained by shifting the sequence of random variables.  If the random variables are identically distributed, then the shift transformation is measure preserving.  In the case of measure preserving or a stationary process, then if the shift transformation is also ergodic (no non-trivial invariant sets), then the Birkhoff ergodic theorem follows and both the weak law of large numbers and the strong law of large numbers follow.  The strong law is equivalent to almost everywhere convergence and the weak law is equivalent to convergence in mean.  Convergence in mean is much easier to prove and on the face of it, a weaker property.  It is a powerful result that these are equivalent in the special case of a finite measure preserving transformation.  The study of shift transformations is a whole subfield in ergodic theory commonly called symbolic dynamics.  There are examples satisfying various types of convergence when considering sequences of random variables or when considering specialized topics such as uniform convergence.
It's always been my feeling that the connection between these fields is under utilized.  Going back many years, there has not been much collaboration between people who study ergodic theory, statistics, probability and more applied areas such as control theory, dynamical systems and machine learning/deep learning.  A deep neural network can be characterized using your drawing on the right.  As sequential data drops into the network (e.g., sentences to be translated), the network generates output.  In simplest terms, a classifier at the end can be viewed as a function $f$ of the transformation determined by the hidden states (e.g., network weights).
In summary, the Birkhoff ergodic theorem is a very general and powerful result that demonstrates the strong law of large numbers holds for many stationary dependent processes which is still not widely considered by statisticians.  Paul Halmos showed that in a topological sense, most ergodic measure preserving transformations are weak mixing but not strong mixing, and are actually rigid and have zero entropy (deterministic).  The deep neural networks today have millions of parameters because we can no longer model our world using positive entropy processes with a limited view of the past (Markov models, HMMs).  I hope this response helps.

Thanks a lot! "a classifier at the end can be viewed as a function  of the transformation determined by the hidden states", what does this mean? I'm also interested in some books for reference on this idea.

This connection seems mostly unexplored.  Here is a reference that discusses what you asked above: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6265.  You might check other articles by Kevin McGoff.  The following paper looks at modeling $\psi$-weakly dependent processes using deep learning https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.00333.   Possibly, this book: https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf (ch. 8).  If you want to delve deeply into the mathematics of deep learning, maybe try Boris Hanin's papers/books: https://boris-hanin.github.io/ (not for the faint of heart).
